# Layers on UICollectionViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uiimage, layer

I currently have a UICollectionViewController with some cells that act as notifications. I also also have a header which contains a button to clear the notifications. When the clear button is pressed, all the cells are removed. When there are no cells remaining I would like to display a image in the center prompting the user to create a new group. How might I do this? I have already tried using the storyboard, but that didn't seem to work.

I want it to look like something similar to this:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set UIImageView in the center of screen horizontally or vertically with Swift, but no more StoryBoard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29099735/how-to-set-uiimageview-in-the-center-of-screen-horizontally-or-vertically-with-s)

Comment: @Nikhil Sridhar  either place a image view behind table view exactly in center , once the count goes zero hide table view , and image view will be shown.